# What database design philosophy is being violated when one table references another table via a non-prime field?

Tags: sql, relational-database

Suppose you have two tables. One of the tables contains thousands of customers indexed by a surrogate key, and a customer name field (which is clearly non-prime). Another table that tracks purchases references customers by their name as opposed to the corresponding surrogate key.

If I'm trying to justify to someone why this is bad (as it obviously is), is there a nameable design philosophy that's being violated? Since a redundancy is being created, intuitively you'd think that the tables are somehow not normalized, but since it concerns a relationship between two different tables it's hard for me personally to see how normalization applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not normalized in 3rd normal form. 3rd Normal Form required that references are done based on a candidate key (i.e. unique key).

In your example, it could be possible that you will have multiple customers with the same name, which means:

1. You cannot enforce a 1:1 relationship between the 2 tables
2. Joins between the 2 tables will not perform well unless you index the name column.

If you are working on a large database this is likely to present problems as you will eventually end up with duplicate names (e.g. John Smith).

Comment: Well if people are happy to accept such a preposterous and outright delusional answer, then so be it.  But just for the record : There is not a single member of the entire set of +- traditional database normal forms (1NF,2NF,3NF,BCNF,4NF,5NF,6NF,ETNF) that says **anything** about foreign keys or even its more or less theoretical underpinning, which is inclusion dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely off base, but normalization and database design theory should take a back seat to good old fashioned program accuracy in this case.  If you have two customers named "John Smith", how can you possibly identify which purchases belong to "John Smith" (the correct John Smith, that is) if the purchases table is keyed off of name?  If this is the case (ie there are no idiotic name mangling strategies for identifying the "correct" John Smith), then the named principle would be "The Principle of Returning the Right Answer". :-)

If the name is being mangled to make John Smith (1) != John Smith (2), the the principle of parsimony applies: all other factors being equal, the simplest of a population of correct solutions is the best solution.  Take your pick.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself when you say that normalization should take a back seat to something else, and then explaining why the stray away from normalization is a bad idea.  Hence the downvote.

Comment: No. Actually I was pointing out that either the design was fatally flawed (ie a query would return the wrong answer), or that any possible solution to make the answer correct (ie making a non-prime customer field unique via some convoluted disambiguation strategy) would be more complex than simply using the most obvious solution - accessing the customer table via primary key.  Nothing contradictory there.